# Show that the amplitude of oscillation grows linearly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the general strategy here? I think if someone just starts me off I should be good to go.

> Given: a harmonic oscillator is driven harmonically at its resonance frequency $\omega$. It's equation of motion is $\ddot x(t) + \omega_0^2x(t)=\frac{f_0}{m}cos(\omega_0t)$. Show that the amplitude of oscillation grows linearly as $x(t)=atcos(\omega_0t-\delta)$.

I found the solution of the diff eq to be $x(t)=\frac{btsin(\omega_0 t)}{2\omega_0}+c_2sin(\omega_0 t)+c_1cos(\omega_0 t)$, where $b=f_0/m$, but what do I *do* with this?

If I look at only the first term of my solution, I see that the amplitude is $\frac{f_0t}{2m\omega_0}$. This grows linearly with time. Great. But how do I relate it to that last part?

Comment: Do you have some initial conditions?

Comment: @copper.hat nope, none are given.

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude
$$
\sqrt{c_1^2+\left(\frac{bt}{2w_0}+c_2\right)^2}
$$
behaves as $\Theta(t)$ for $t\to\infty$.

---

For the more specific formula, these physical tasks often assume that the system is at rest for $t<0$ and at $t=0$ the forcing on the right side is switched on. Which translates to zero initial conditions and thus $c_1=c_2=0$. Then use $\sin(u)=\cos(u-\frac\pi2)$.